# Defining a "pathway" from a list of points

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks, visualization, documentation

#### 1. Description of Pathway

**1.1 Preliminary Definitions**

Let $A=[-2,2]^2$, where $\text{Area}(A)=16$ and  $\lceil \cdot\rceil$ is the ceiling function.

For $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}$, let $\left\{U_i\right\}_{i=1}^{\lceil 16/\varepsilon\rceil}$ be a sequence of pair-wise disjoint sets covering $A$, where for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$, each $\text{Area}(U_i)$ should equal constant $\varepsilon$, such that the difference between the total sum of all $\text{Area}(U_i)$ and $\text{Area}(A)$ is minimized. Furthermore, take point $s_i\in U_i$ where set $\mathcal{S}=\left\{s_i:i\in\mathbb{N},1\le i\le \lceil 16/\varepsilon \rceil\right\}$ is a sample of points.

**1.2 Description of Pathway**

Suppose we want a "pathway" of line segments between all points in each sample such that if $d(Q,R)$ is the Euclidean-distance between points $Q$ and $R$, we:

1. Take a point $x_0$ from $\mathcal{S}$
2. Take a point from $\mathcal{S}$ with smallest euclidean distance from point $x_0\in\mathcal{S}$. The point is denoted $x_1$, where we take $d(x_0,x_1)$. (If more than one point has the smallest Euclidean distance from $x_0$, take either point).
3. Take a point in $\mathcal{S}$ (excluding $x_0$) with smallest euclidean distance from $x_1$. The point is denoted $x_2$, where we take $d(x_1,x_2)$. (If more than one point has the smallest Euclidean distance from $x_1$, we take either point).
4. Take a point in $\mathcal{S}$ (excluding $x_0$ and $x_1$) with smallest euclidean distance from $x_2$. The point is denoted $x_3$ then take $d(x_2,x_3)$. (If more than one point has the smallest Euclidean distance from $x_2$, we take either point).
5. Repeat the process excluding points $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,$ etc. until all points in the sample are "denoted". (This should occur $\lceil 16/\varepsilon \rceil -1$ times.)
6. Take the largest subset of $i$-values, such that $x_{i}$ has the $r_{i}$-th smallest Euclidean distance from $x_{i-1}$ (compared to points in $\mathcal{S}\setminus\left\{x_i\right\}$) such that $r_i$ is not an outlier in:
   $$\left\{r_t: t\in\mathbb{N}, 1\le t\le \lceil 16/\varepsilon \rceil -1\right\}$$

#### 2. Attempt

Throughout the attempt consider the following questions:

**Question:** Is there a faster code for displaying sec. 1.1 and 1.2? If not, how do we improve the attempts of sec. 2.1 and 2.2?

**2.1: First Part of Attempt**

Below is the attempt to code the description.

We'll start with first half:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
A = Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}]; (* Set A, i.e. [-2,2]x[-2,2] *)
U = DiscretizeRegion[A, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 
     1.5}]; (* Makes the area of all disjoint sets "nearly equal" .1 *)
S = AnnotationValue[{U, 2}, 
  MeshCellCentroid] (* A list of points from each disjoint set in U *)
Show[U, Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[], 
   Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}]}], 
 Graphics[{Red, Point[S]}]] (*Illustration of the code above *)
```

[image]

Below are the following issues:

1. The triangles don't have equal area
2. The only shapes that I know for `DiscretizeRegion` are triangles. (I want arbitrary shapes, e.g. squares and rectangles, which cover $A=[-2,2]^2$). The arbitrary shapes (i.e., $\left\{U_i\right\}_{i=1}^{\lceil 16/\varepsilon \rceil}$ in sec. 1.1) may "over-cover" $A$ as long as the total area of the shapes is minimized.
3. <s>I'm unable to choose a random point in each of the triangles. The best I could do was take the centroids.</s> (This was resolved with [@Syed's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288866/defining-a-pathway-from-a-list-of-points?noredirect=1#comment719318_288866)).

**2.2: Second Part of Attempt**

Below is the second half of the code. We attempt to define a pathway for a given $\mathcal{S}$ (sec. 1.1)

```
(* Note we created a table so the q-variable (in the table) can 
   vary from q=1 to Length[S] *)
 T = Table[{
   X[1, q] = S[[q]], (*Here X1=x0=S[[q]], the q-
   th point of the sample in the first half of code *)
   Y[1, q] = DeleteCases[S, X[1, q]], (*Deletes X1=
   x0 from the sample S in sec. 1.1*)
   X[x_, q] := Nearest[Y[x - 1, q], X[x - 1, q], 1][[1]],         
   (* Takes X2=x1, X3=x2, X4=x3,... in sec. 1.2 *)
   Y[x_, q] := DeleteCases[Y[x - 1, q], X[x, q]], (* Deletes X1=x0, 
   X2=x1, X3=x2,... from the sample S *)
   P[q] = Table[X[x, q], {x, 1, Length[S]}], (* 
   List of all points in the inital pathway of points in X *)
   r[i_, q] := 
    Flatten[Position[Nearest[S, P[q][[i]], Length[S]], 
      P[q][[i + 1]]]], (* Lists value r_i  where P[[
   i+1]] is the r_i th smallest value from P[[i]],
   see sec. 1.2 crit. 6 *)
   ListofAllr[q] = 
    Flatten[Table[r[i, q], {i, 1, Length[S] - 1}]], (* 
   List of r[i] in sec. 1.2, crit. 6 for all i *)
   IndexofNonOutliers[q] = 
    Flatten[Position[ListofAllr[q], 
      Alternatives @@ DeleteAnomalies[ListofAllr[q]]]], (* 
   Lists Index of non-outliers in the list of r[i] *)
   D1[q] = Table[P[q][[x]], Evaluate[{x, IndexofNonOutliers[q]}]], 
   (*Excludes integer i where r_i are outliers *)
   arrow[coord_, e_] := 
    Piecewise[{{Style[Arrow[coord], Red, Thickness[.01], 
        Arrowheads[0.06]], 
       Boole[MemberQ[N /@ D1[q], First@coord]] == 0}, {Style[
        Arrow[coord], Black, Thickness[.01], Arrowheads[0.06]], 
       Boole[MemberQ[N /@ D1[q], First@coord]] == 
        1}}], (*Labels direction of pathway*)
   Edge[q] = 
    PathGraph[Range[Length[P[q]]], VertexCoordinates -> P[q], 
     EdgeShapeFunction -> arrow, ImageSize -> 300, 
     PlotRangePadding -> .2, 
     VertexLabels -> 
      Table[i -> Subscript[x, i - 1], {i, Length[P[q]]}]],
   (* 'Edge' Illustrates Pathway {x_i} (sec. 1.2). 
   Blue represents the segments we want to keep. 
   Red represents the segments we wish to discard. *)
    Show[U, 
    Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[], 
      Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}]}], Graphics[{Red, Point[S]}], 
    Edge[q]],
   (* 'Show' graphs parititions, samples, 
   and the "pathway" of every point in the sample, starting with 
   x0=X1=S[[q]] *)
   DistanceD1[q] = 
    Table[EuclideanDistance[P[q][[x]], P[q][[x + 1]]], 
     Evaluate[{x, IndexofNonOutliers[q]}]]}, 
  (*Takes the length of all segments 
    in the pathway whose start-points have index i where r[i] is
    not an outlier 'Listofallr'*)
  , {q, 1, Length[S]}]; (* Table ends *)
GraphofAllPathways = 
 Table[T[[r, Length[T[[1]]] - 1]], {r, 1, 
   Length[S]}] (* Takes the graph of all Pathways in S *)
DD[r_] := 
 T[[r, Length[
    T[[1]]]]] (* Applying 'DistanceD1' or d (sec. 1.2) for 
   q=1,2,...,Length[S] *)

(*Ignore the remaining code below*)
PD[r_] :=  DD[r]/Total[DD[r]]; (* We convert length of line 
segments in 'GraphofD1'(i.e., 'DistanceD1') into a probability 
distribution whose elements sum to 1. *)
Entrop = Table[-N[Total[PD[r] Log[2, PD[r]]]], {r, 1, Length[S]}] 
(*Entropy of Pathway*)
GraphofAllPathways[[Flatten[ Position[Entrop, Max[Entrop]]]]] 
(*Takes "pathways" with the highest entropy*)
```

Here is an example of an output:

[image]

However, there are two problems:

1. From the first half of the code (i.e., `DiscretizeRegion`) if the `"Area"` is approx. less than 1.73, the code takes too long to end. Infact, in the second half of the code, for timing purposes; we set the `"Area"` to 2.
2. <s>I want to repeat the code `Length[S]` number of times (creating a second variable, i.e. replace the `6` of `S[[6]]` with `q=[1,…,Length[S]]`). I was unable to complete this, which I believe is due to recurrence relations `X` and `Y`</s> (This was resolved using `Table`; however, the former adds extra time to the computation.)

**Edit:** I managed to fix the simplified version of the code (which is now deleted) with this version.

**Question (Reasked):** Is there a faster code for displaying sec. 1.1 and 1.2? If not, how do we improve the attempts of sec. 2.1 and 2.2?

Comment: `rpts = RandomPoint /@ MeshPrimitives[U, 2];` and `Show[U, Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[], 
   Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}]}], Graphics[{Red, Point[rpts]}]]` to generate random points inside all polygons.

Comment: @Syed Thanks. How do we cover `A` with arbitrary shapes of the same area, such that if the arbitrary shapes "over-cover" `A`, the total area of all the shapes is minimized.

Comment: I don't know, but you ask a separate question to cover that part only. I am happy to see that you are making progress.

Comment: See this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288950/covering-a-rectangle-with-arbitrary-shapes-of-equal-area-where-the-total-area-o?noredirect=1&lq=1), if it's easier to answer.