# Covering a rectangle with arbitrary shapes of equal area, where the total area of the shapes is minimized

Tags: graphics, mesh, code-request, documentation

This is a follow up to [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/288866/34171), which had to be broken down since it was too long.

#### 1. Definitions

Let $A=[-2,2]^2$, where $\text{Area}(A)=16$ and  $\lceil \cdot\rceil$ is the ceiling function.

For $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}$, let $\left\{U_i\right\}_{i=1}^{\lceil 16/\varepsilon\rceil}$ be a sequence of pair-wise disjoint sets covering $A$, where for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$, each $\text{Area}(U_i)$ should equal constant $\varepsilon$, such that the difference between the total sum of all $\text{Area}(U_i)$ and $\text{Area}(A)$ is minimized. Furthermore, take point $s_i\in U_i$ where set $\mathcal{S}=\left\{s_i:i\in\mathbb{N},1\le i\le \lceil 16/\varepsilon \rceil\right\}$ is a sample of points.

#### 2. Attempt to Convert The Definitions to Code

Below is my attempt to describe sec. 1:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
A = Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}]; (* Set A, i.e. [-2,2]x[-2,2] *)
U = DiscretizeRegion[A, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 
     1.8}]; (* Makes the area of all partitions "almost equal" to .1*)
S = RandomPoint /@ 
  MeshPrimitives[U, 2];  (* A list of points from each partition *)
Show[U, Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], FaceForm[], 
   Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}]}], 
 Graphics[{Red, Point[S]}]] (*Illustration of the code above *)
```

[image]

The problem is:

1. The triangles don't have equal area.
2. The only shapes I know for `DiscretizeRegion` are triangles. (I want arbitrary shapes, e.g. squares and rectangles, which cover $A$). The arbitrary shapes (i.e., $\left\{U_i\right\}_{i=1}^{\lceil 16/\varepsilon \rceil}$ in sec. 1.1) can "over-cover" $A$ as long as the total area of the shapes is minimized.

**Question:** How do we solve the problems 1. and 2. in sec. 2?

Answer (score 4):

One possible way is using clustering:

```
clusters = 
  FindClusters[RandomPoint[Rectangle[{-2, -2}, {2, 2}], 35000], 20, 
   Method -> "KMeans"];

Show[{mesh = VoronoiMesh[Mean /@ clusters, {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}], 
  Graphics[{{RandomColor[], Point[#]} & /@ clusters}]}]
```

[image]

But areas of polygons are not the same:

```
area = AnnotationValue[{mesh, 2}, MeshCellMeasure]
```

> {0.706412, 0.620505, 0.712833, 0.698375, 0.765174, 0.856666, 
> 0.894983, 0.786204, 0.742506, 0.81401, 0.826056, 0.90378, 0.788876, 
> 0.940046, 0.776065, 0.936281, 0.793973, 0.808283, 0.83067, 0.798302}

If you don't care about non-overlapping, you can try to scale each polygon to make the same area:

```
factor = Sqrt[Max[area]/area];
cover = MapThread[
   CanonicalizeRegion[Scale[#1, #2, #3 ]] &, {MeshPrimitives[mesh, 
     2], factor, AnnotationValue[{mesh, 2}, MeshCellCentroid]}];

Area /@ cover
```

> {0.899719, 0.899719, 0.899719, 0.899719, 0.899719, 0.899719, 
> 0.899719, 0.899719, 0.899719, 0.899719, 0.899719, 0.899719, 0.899719, 
> 0.899719, 0.899719, 0.899719, 0.899719, 0.899719, 0.899719, 0.899719}

```
Graphics[{Riffle[RandomColor[Length[cover]], cover] }]
```

[image]

But if you want squares, why not just partition into the same squares?

```
rec = Flatten[
   Table[Rectangle[{i, j}, {i + 1, j + 1}], {i, -2, 2, 1}, {j, -2, 2, 
     1}]];
```

Comment: Suppose we want to control the area of all the smaller polygons (or closed curve), so that they have a specific, equivalent area, where we take a point from each shape. How do we do this?

Comment: @Arbuja RandomPoint or RegionCentroid ?

Comment: Either is fine.

Comment: Just apply it , RandomPoint /@ cover or RegionCentroid /@ cover

Comment: How do we make all polygons a specific area, such as $.6$?

Comment: @Arbuja you need 26.6667 polygons so I don't think it's possible to have such cover..

Comment: or if you don't care overlapping increase # of cover like 32 and set factor : factor = Sqrt[.6/area]

Comment: I understand, but in the post it’s said “over-covering” is allowed as long as the total area of all the shapes is minimized. Does `factor=Sqrt[.6/area]` allow this. (I  would prefer “no-overlapping” at the boundaries since in sec. 1 of my post, the covers should be pairwise disjoint.”