# Fixing a code which covers $[-k,k]\times[-k,k]$ for a given $k\in\mathbb{N}$, with smaller rectangles of equal area?

Tags: graphics, mesh, code-review, broken-code

**Motivation:** From [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/289421/34171) we, initially, wanted to cover a rectangle using smaller, non-overlapping rectangles with the same area: the difference between the total area of the smaller rectangles and the area of the original rectangle should be zero or positive and close to zero *as possible*.

Using [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/289424/34171):

```
rad = {{-1, -1}, {1, 1}};
epsilon = 7/10;
a = Area[Rectangle @@ rad];
n = Ceiling[a/epsilon];
dn = Divisors[n];
dim = Transpose[{dn, Reverse[dn]}];
rdim = RandomChoice[dim];
b = n*eps;
nr = r*x /. 
   Solve[b == Times @@ Subtract @@ (r*x), x, PositiveReals][[1]];
nr = # - (Plus @@ nr/2 - Plus @@ r/2) & /@ nr // RootReduce;
Partition[
   Table[i, {i, nr[[1, 1]], nr[[2, 1]], Abs[nr[[1, 1]] - nr[[2, 1]]]/
     rdim[[1]]}], 2, 1] // RootReduce;
Partition[
   Table[i, {i, nr[[1, 2]], nr[[2, 2]], Abs[nr[[1, 2]] - nr[[2, 2]]]/
     rdim[[2]]}], 2, 1] // RootReduce;
Transpose /@ Tuples[{%%, %}];
Graphics[{Rectangle @@ r, EdgeForm[Red], Green, Opacity[0.5], 
  Rectangle @@@ %}]
```

we want to cover a square of the form $[-k,k]\times[-k,k]$ for a given $k\in\mathbb{N}$

I attempted to define the code in the answer in terms of variable `k`

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Unprotect[Tr]
rad[k_] := 
 rad[k] = {{-k, -k}, {k, k}}; (* Define a sequence of rectangles with k *)
epsilon = 7/10;
a[k_] := a[k] = Area[Rectangle @@ rad[k]];
n[k_] := n[k] = Ceiling[a[k]/epsilon];
dn[k_] := dn[k] = Divisors[n[k]];
dim[k_] := dim[k] = Transpose[{dn[k], Reverse[dn[k]]}];
rdim[k_] := rdim[k] = RandomChoice[dim[k]];
b[k_] := b[k] = n[k]*epsilon;
nr[k_] := 
  nr[k] = rad[k]*x /. 
    Solve[b[k] == Times @@ Subtract @@ (rad[k]*x), x, 
      PositiveReals][[1]];
nr[k_] := 
  nr[k] = # - (Plus @@ nr[k]/2 - Plus @@ rad/2) & /@ nr[k] // 
    RootReduce;
Partk1[k_] := 
  Partk1[k] = 
   Partition[
     Table[i, {i, nr[k][[1, 1]], nr[k][[2, 1]], 
       Abs[nr[k][[1, 1]] - nr[k][[2, 1]]]/rdim[k][[1]]}], 2, 1] // 
    RootReduce;
Partk2[k_] := 
  Partk2[k] = 
   Partition[
     Table[i, {i, nr[k][[1, 2]], nr[k][[2, 2]], 
       Abs[nr[[1, 2]] - nr[k][[2, 2]]]/rdim[k][[2]]}], 2, 1] // 
    RootReduce;
Tr[k_] := Tr[k] = Transpose /@ Tuples[{Partk1[k], Partk2[k]}];
U[k_] := U[k] = Rectangle @@@ Tr[k]
S[k_] := S[k] = RegionCentroid /@ U[k]
G[k_] := G[k] = 
  Show[Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], FaceForm[], 
     Rectangle @@ rad[k], EdgeForm[{Thick, Green}], U[k]}], 
   Graphics[{Black, Point[S[k]]}]]

 G[3] (* Code we want to output*)
```

We want the output of `G[3]` to be a picture of a square $[-3,3]\times[-3,3]$ bordered in red and with coverings of smaller, green rectangles that have the same area. (We assume, because of the second `nr[k]` (i.e., the recurrence relation), `Partk1[k]`, and `Partk2[k]`; I get the following errors.)

```
$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of RootReduce[(#1-(Apply[<<2>>] Power[<<2>>]-Times[<<2>>])&)/@nr[3]].

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of RootReduce[(#1-(Apply[<<2>>] Power[<<2>>]-Times[<<2>>])&)/@nr[3]].

$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of RootReduce[(#1-(Apply[<<2>>] Power[<<2>>]-Times[<<2>>])&)/@nr[3]].

General::stop: Further output of $RecursionLimit::reclim2 will be suppressed during this calculation.

Table::iterb: Iterator {i,Hold[nr[3][[1,1]]],Hold[nr[3][[2,1]]],Hold[Abs[nr[3][[1,1]]-nr[<<1>>][[2,1]]]/rdim[3][[1]]]} does not have appropriate bounds.

Table::iterb: Iterator {i,Hold[nr[3][[1,1]]],Hold[nr[3][[2,1]]],Hold[Abs[nr[3][[1,1]]-nr[<<1>>][[2,1]]]/rdim[3][[1]]]} does not have appropriate bounds.

Table::iterb: Iterator {i,Hold[nr[3][[1,1]]],Hold[nr[3][[2,1]]],Hold[Abs[nr[3][[1,1]]-nr[<<1>>][[2,1]]]/rdim[3][[1]]]} does not have appropriate bounds.

General::stop: Further output of Table::iterb will be suppressed during this calculation.

Part::partd: Part specification nr[[1,2]] is longer than depth of object.

Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {i,{i,Hold[nr[3][[1,2]]],Hold[nr[3][[2,2]]],Hold[Abs[nr[[1,2]]-Part[<<3>>]]/rdim[3][[2]]]}} cannot be transposed.

Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {{i,Hold[nr[3][[1,1]]],Hold[nr[3][[2,1]]],Hold[Abs[nr[<<1>>][[1,1]]-Part[<<3>>]]/rdim[3][[1]]]},i} cannot be transposed.
```

**Question:** How do we fix the second `nr[k_]`, `Partk1`, `Partk2` and `Tr` so we could fix the code?

Comment: Please perform some troubleshooting yourself, at a minimum to identify the origin of the recursive call.

Comment: @MarcoB I tried to fix the mistake but I don’t where it is? I assume it’s at `Partk1` and `Partk2` but I don’t know how to check.

Comment: @MarcoB Nevermind, I think it's at the second line of `nr[k]` (the recurrence relation).

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3001881?p_p_auth=JXU6rsER).

Comment: What is the point of using `something[k_]:=something[k_]=...` each time you define something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is really not worth any fixing. Your style of writing code (programing) is really bad.

But anyway the question was how to fix it - so I leave it in its original form, only fixing the least amount to make it work. But in fact the code should be entirely rebuild.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
rad[k_] := 
 rad[k] = {{-k, -k}, {k, 
    k}};(*Define a sequence of rectangles with k*)epsilon = 7/10;
a[k_] := a[k] = Area[Rectangle @@ rad[k]];
n[k_] := n[k] = Ceiling[a[k]/epsilon];
dn[k_] := dn[k] = Divisors[n[k]];
dim[k_] := dim[k] = Transpose[{dn[k], Reverse[dn[k]]}];
rdim[k_] := rdim[k] = RandomChoice[dim[k]];
b[k_] := b[k] = n[k]*epsilon;
nnr[k_] := 
  nnr[k] = rad[k]*x /. 
    Solve[b[k] == Times @@ Subtract @@ (rad[k]*x), x, 
      PositiveReals][[1]];
nr[k_] := 
  nr[k] = # - (Plus @@ nnr[k]/2 - Plus @@ rad[k]/2) & /@ nnr[k] // 
    RootReduce;
Partk1[k_] := 
  Partk1[k] = 
   Partition[
     Table[i, {i, nr[k][[1, 1]], nr[k][[2, 1]], 
       Abs[nr[k][[1, 1]] - nr[k][[2, 1]]]/rdim[k][[1]]}], 2, 1] // 
    RootReduce;
Partk2[k_] := 
  Partk2[k] = 
   Partition[
     Table[i, {i, nr[k][[1, 2]], nr[k][[2, 2]], 
       Abs[nr[k][[1, 2]] - nr[k][[2, 2]]]/rdim[k][[2]]}], 2, 1] // 
    RootReduce;
tr[k_] := tr[k] = Transpose /@ Tuples[{Partk1[k], Partk2[k]}];
U[k_] := U[k] = Rectangle @@@ tr[k]
S[k_] := S[k] = RegionCentroid /@ U[k]
G[k_] := G[k] = 
  Show[Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Red}], FaceForm[], 
     Rectangle @@ rad[k], EdgeForm[{Thick, Green}], U[k]}], 
   Graphics[{Black, Point[S[k]]}]]
G[3]
```

Comment: If I were to rewrite the code, what would I need to do?

Comment: @Arbuja You could start by naming the variables more explicitly so that people can understand what they are referring to. I am not great at making readable Mathematica code, but naming things well I believe I do.